# .htaccess 301 redirect: redirect url via string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

After a Joomla site upgrade I need to redirect every url which contains a string to another url. It is a Joomla site which ran SOBI2 and a few other components so the url could be:

```
?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&sobi2Id=101748&lang=de
```

I tried the following for SOBI in the .htaccess with no success.

```
RewriteCond%{QUERY_STRING} .*option=com_sobi.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.de/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a **?** at the end of the target path to remove the query strings.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*option=com_sobi.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.de/? [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser's cache before using this code.